# Sencha Touch 1.1 scrolling bug with Ext.form.FormPanel - disappears under URL bar

Tags: ios, sencha-touch

I have a FormPanel being created like this:

```
Modal.EmailPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, { 
dock: 'top',
id: 'emailPanel',
name: 'emailPanel',
standardSubmit : false, 
styleHtmlContent: false,
width: 200,
height: window.innerHeight - (Ext.is.Phone ? 20 : g_topToolbarHeight),
scroll: 'vertical',
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch'
},
items: [
```

... etc.

What happens is that at first it displays correctly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQXCB.png

But as soon as it is scrolled, part of it disappears under Safari's URL bar:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryW8Q.png

I am new to Sencha Touch so I'm not very sure what the issue could be. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that when you scroll down your page that cannot fir inside the browser windows it reveals the bottom section and hides the upper?
Well this is the natual scroll behavior of any browser... even in this page, that cannor fit he window, when you scroll it the upper part slide under the url bar... am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, missing something :) The "Email Page" bar is not part of the FormPanel and is not scrollable content. It remains fixed at the top of the screen when the form is scrolled. Typically at least. This design pattern works well for all of our other dialogs, in Android and iOS, in landscape and on portrait, but THIS particular one - despite being built similarly - is giving me trouble. I am missing something, too. :/

Comment: ah ok, so first of all its a native application :), im not familiar with ios interface.
What you want is slide everything, including the search bar? Could you post the rest of the view, including the items and their layout?

Comment: Not native, no... Those screenshots are iOS Safari. It does behave differently on iOS/Android/etc in different orientations though!